# What topics to cover for an introduction to JavaScript for web development

Tags: javascript, web-development, web

To cut to the point, I'm going to be working at a web design company in a few month. My soon-to be boss (which I'll call 'Bob') was told I'm exceptional at JavaScript (I had been using it for years). And now, for the first week or two of work, Bob wants me to teach two of his employees JavaScript.

My problem is, I am knowledgeable in JavaScript for the creation of games and custom server applications, but not specifically in web development. I have taught JavaScript before professionally, but that was basics of standard JavaScript. I was wondering if there was a site or other source I could visit that has a resource for those already skilled in JS to learn the basics of JS for web development. Just a rundown of the most basic functions, and how to reference objects on a page, etc., for those who are already skilled in JS and would be bored to death by having to go over the basics of programming all over again in some course. Just to clarify, the course I teach to my soon-to-be coworkers doesn't need to be that in-depth, just enough so that they can edit someone else's script, understand it at a basic level, and manipulate it to their liking.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really just need one link. This one:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Which is the info for js tag in StackOverflow. Sorry, I had forgoten this one when you asked there.